# Minecraft Nether ceiling - portals not linking

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm having a lot of problems linking two portals. I've managed to link a portal in the Overworld to the nether ceiling successfully, but these other  2 portals just aren't linking to the correct place.

Overworld portal -549, 79, 584 / Location on ceiling -73, 128, 72
Now when I go through the portal on the nether ceiling it's linking to this portal

```
-576, 59, 653
```

If I go back through the incorrect portal in the overworld, that goes back to its linked location in the netherworld. So one way only.

Now I think its linking to it because it's the closest, is there any way I can solve this, or do i need to make one somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

oddly enough, the math seems to be off here. for reference, one block in the Nether is equivalent **horizontally**, not vertically, to 8 blocks in the Overworld, so a portal located at `1, 0, 1` would create/link to a portal at `8, 0, 8`. this means that, with some quick math, your Nether ceiling portal *should* be appearing at `-584, 128, 576` in the Overworld.

but, i digress. even if the math were off, it should *not* be creating a portal at `-576, 59, 653` like you say it is. Nether portal linking has actually been finicky since the 1.18 snapshots -- it did similar in 1.16, both of which are understandable because each update did massive change to generation in the Overworld and Nether, respectively.

you'll need to go into the Nether, and move the portal to the *actual* coordinates of  `-69, 128, 73`, which is where it should've been placed when you went through the portal in the Overworld.

Comment: You just have to mine the portal on the ceiling and move it about 100 blocks in any direction. That should fix your issue

Comment: that's essentially what my final paragraph/sentence says, albeit more specifically. it's good practice in these events to make sure you place them at the coordinates they *should* be in to prevent any potential mismatches down the line.